# Is there anyway to indicate to SQL Server that a column is ever increasing?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with a table that contains roughly one billion rows. It has a timestamp column that is, by its nature, ever increasing.

If I were to query this table and ask for records that were created in the past 5 minutes (using the timestamp in the **where** clause), SQL Server will **scan** an entire index to get the results and it could take several minutes.

However, because this column is ever increasing and therefore ordered, SQL Server *could* use a more sophisticated search technique to find these records, as if it were an index. I understand that SQL Server doesn't know these columns are ordered (outside of some stats/distribution info), and it cannot guarantee that they're ordered, either, so it cannot do this.

Is there perhaps an "ever increasing" constraint, whereby any new rows added have to have a timestamp column value that is more than or equal to the previous one? It seems like there should be a way to take advantage of the natural order of this column.

Comment: And why don't you just index the column?

Comment: If your most common query on this table is based on the timestamp, then it might be that this column should be the clustering key (potentially non-unique to allow multiple records with the same timestamp if that can happen). For log tables with high throughput it often makes a lot more sense to make the created date the clustering key, which is not limited to be ever increasing, but if it is you will not get any issues with page splits, and your searches for records in the last 5 minutes will be rapid.

Comment: @stickybit because its a large table, and there is only a few queries that use this column

Comment: @GarethD agreed. This would be ideal

Comment: @EvanPayne: So? Disk space is cheap nowadays, so the amount the index needs shouldn't be an issue. And queries not using the column shouldn't be affected at all by it (If you experienced otherwise and suspect this slows the other queries, you should post a new question including the `CREATE` statements of the table and index, the (a) query and the execution plan showing that the index is used.)

Comment: @stickybit the concern wouldn't be disk space so much as slowing down updates, inserts, deletes

Comment: @EvanPayne: Did you *actually* experience problems? If not, there might be none.

Comment: @stickybit No, I did not create the index on it to see. Creating an index is quite the process for the organization I work in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such constraint/option/etc. SQL server does not know what is relationship between tables or indexes... To be honest I think you should consider creating an index on that column. The other option would be to create partitions on that table based on the timestamp column, then you should be able to force SQL to scan only given partition. However new index is much simple and more flexible change.